# Почему WinMerge не распознает кириллицу?

Tags: python-3.x, кодировка, bat

У меня есть код в питоне, который создает бат файл с кодом:

```
@echo off

"{путь до winmerge}/WinMergeU.exe" "{путь с кириллицей 1}" "{путь с кириллицей 2}"
```

При создании бат файла я указываю кодировку UTF-8.

Когда я запускаю файл, открывается Winmerge с вставленными путями, но почему-то он не распознает символы кириллицы. Но почему он не может их распознать?

Пробовал запустить просто `"{путь до winmerge}/WinMergeU.exe" "{путь с кириллицей 1}" "{путь с кириллицей 2}"` через терминал (без бат файла) и всё работает - пути в Winmerge распознаются.

Добавлял в файл строку `chcp 65001`.

Еще проверял кодировку файла с помощью Notepad'а, ставил UTF-8 и UTF-8-BOM - с обеими тоже не работает.

Comment: Bat файл созданный вручную работает?

Comment: Попробуйте bat файл сохранить в кодировке cp866

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy нет, тоже не распознает кириллицу

Comment: @insolor да, помогло, спасибо большое. Но почему оно стало работать с этой кодировкой?

Comment: Ваша задача научиться создавать bat файлы в кодировке 866. Питон тут не причём. Ещё лучше обойтись без bat файла. Вы можете вызвать нужный процесс напрямую через `os.system` или `win32`.

Comment: @fgrd4035 по историческим причинам (по причине глубоких корней Windows в ОС MS DOS) кодировка консоли и бат-файлов досовская, и замена кодировки на cp866 часто помогает. Возможно с PowerShell дела обстоят лучше, и он UTF-8 понимает, но я с ним не работал, не могу ничего гарантировать.